# How to write into registry using VC++ 2010?

Tags: visual-c++, registry

HKEY CURRENT USER \software \microsoft\ windowsNT \CurrentVersion\ AppCompatFlags "application path" = RUNASXP3

I want to create an application which runs in default XP mode on windows 7 when i run the application so, i want to write into the registry as in the link above.

I am building the application in VC++ 2010, i want to write into the above registry through the program, so that when i run the program it runs in XP mode. How to do this..?

Comment: What happens when you try `RegSetValueEx()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+registry)? It appears the search results cover your question quite well.

For instance:

- [Working with the Windows Registry in C++](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Working-with-the-Windows-Registry-in-C-plus-plus/)
- [Microsoft Visual C++ Tutorials - Keeping Values in the Registry](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/articles/regvalues.htm)
- [Editing Windows Registry - C++](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread98303.html)

You can also [search on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+registry).

Comment: Well, we can't really help you if you don't tell us what you tried and what went wrong.